# How do I match string till end of text file?

Tags: ruby, regex, string-matching

In this line of code I want it to match the string from 'Review Notes \50optional\51' till the end of the text file. How can I do this?

```
reviewNotes = contents.match(/Review Notes \50optional\51\n==================(.*?)/m)[1].strip
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Review Notes \50optional\51.*$
```

Comment: Shouldn't the backslashes be escaped? Or does Ruby detect that this backreference doesn't exist and treats it literally? Also, `$` always matches the end of the line, not the end of the file in Ruby. There is no multiline mode (`/m` is in Ruby what `/s` is in other regex flavors).

Comment: @Tim, Maybe `\50` is octal? If not, it should be escaped.

Comment: Yes those are octal codes for brackets. And thanks, your answer works!

Answer (score 2):

```
if subject =~ /Review Notes \\50optional\\51.*\z/m
    match = $&
else
    match = ""
end
```